# Is it possible to create a 2d json array with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
tab:

 num │ value_two │ value_three │ value_four 
─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼────────────
  1  │ a         │ A           │ 4.0
  2  │ a         │ A2          │ 75.0
  3  │ b         │ A3          │ 7.0
```

I want to create a 2D json array like this

```
[[1,"a","A",4.0],[2,"a","A2",75.0],[3,"b","A3",7.0]]
```

I have tried two things:

First `SELECT json_agg(tab) FROM tab` but it returns an array of objects.

The second thing that I tried kinda works, the only detail is that it returns a 2d string array.

`SELECT json_agg(ARRAY[num::TEXT,value_two,value_three,value_four::TEXT]) FROM tab`

```
[["1","a","A","4.0"],["2","a","A2",75.0],["3","b","A3","7.0"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
=# select json_agg(json_build_array(num, value_two, value_three, value_four)) as answer
  from tab;
                             answer                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 [[1, "a", "A", 4.0], [2, "a", "A2", 75.0], [3, "b", "A3", 7.0]]
(1 row)
```

Native PostgreSQL arrays like the one you created with

```
ARRAY[num::TEXT,value_two,value_three,value_four::TEXT]
```

are strictly typed, which is why you had to cast `num` and `value_four` to `text`.

To get the type mixing allowed in JSON, use `json_build_array()`, instead.